# Mount Netapp NFS share permanently on RHEL 6.4

Tags: linux, shell, mount, nfs, netapp

I am trying to mount a volume on a RHEL 6.4 virtual machine permanently.

My fstab entry is as:

```
172.17.4.228:/bp_nfs_test1       /mnt1   nfs   rsize=8192,wsize=8192,intr
```

And I mounted the volume as:

```
mount 172.17.4.228:/bp_nfs_test1       /mnt1
```

When I run df -h I can see the volume and able to access it properly.

But when I reboot the VM, the mount is gone and not able to access it anymore even though the entry in /etc/fstab is present

I have to manually mount the volume again (mount -a), then only I am able to see my volume in df -h and access it.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: The network isn't up when fstab is read, so nfs mounts won't come online.

Answer (score 1):

The mount process on boot is very early, so your network won't be online thus preventing the nfs share from being mounted.  You'll need to enable *netfs*, which manages network file shares, and runs after the network is up. Your desired process is:

1. Standard mounts processed.
2. NFS share is skipped during initial mounts (by adding _netdev to options).
3. After network is online, *netfs* will process network file systems like nfs and bring them online.

To prevent automounter for attempting to mount your nfs share before the network services are available, add *_netdev* to your options:

```
172.17.4.228:/bp_nfs_test1       /mnt1   nfs   rsize=8192,wsize=8192,intr,_netdev
```

Enable *netfs*:

```
chkconfig netfs on
```

Alternatively, you could also configure the share through the /etc/auto.master configuration and have it mount when the share is accessed.